# Remove object in nested structure by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, key

I have an array with objects, that can have children, the children have the same structure as the parent, it's just object nesting basically.

**I'm wondering how I can delete one of the objects by key. For example I want to delete the object with id: 1 (which is nested in a children array of another object)**

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [],
  }
]
```

#### Moving children up

Would it be possible? If an object with children is deleted, that the children move up to the root?

#### I've tried

I tried reworking the following function, which returns all id's from my data structure, so it fetches the id, and if there's children, fetches the id's inside those children. But how do I go about deleting an object with that id?

```
export function flattenFindAttribute (data, attribute) {
  return data.map(item => [item[attribute], ...flattenFindAttribute(item.children)]).flat()
}
```

Comment: Are your obj.id values always unique, across the objects?

Comment: Yes they are, they come from the database.

Comment: Are the Id's unique. Say can a parent Id be the same as a child Id?

Comment: No the id will always be unique, in all levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a recursive `function` call and use **[`Array#splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** to remove the searched `object`.

This is how should be your code:

```
function removeId(data, id) {
  data.forEach((o, i) => {
    if (o.id && o.id === id) {
      data.splice(i, 1);
      return true;
    } else if (o.children) {
      removeId(o.children, id);
    }
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
const data = [{
    id: 2,
    children: [{
      id: 1,
      children: []
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [],
  }
];

function removeId(data, id) {
  data.forEach((o, i) => {
    if (o.id && o.id === id) {
      data.splice(i, 1);
      return true;
    } else if (o.children) {
      removeId(o.children, id);
    }
  });
}

removeId(data, 1);
console.log(data);
```

### Edit:

If you want to push all the deleted item `children` into its parent `children` array, you just need to pass a third param to your function to keep trace of the parent `object`:

```
function removeId(data, id, parent) {
  data.forEach((o, i) => {
    if (o.id && o.id === id) {
      if (parent) {
        o.children.forEach(c => parent.children.push(c));
      }
      data.splice(i, 1);
      return true;
    } else if (o.children) {
      removeId(o.children, id, o);
    }
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var data = [{
    id: 2,
    children: [{
      id: 1,
      children: [1, 2]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [],
  }
];

function removeId(data, id, parent) {
  data.forEach((o, i) => {
    if (o.id && o.id === id) {
      if (parent) {
        o.children.forEach(c=> parent.children.push(c));
      }
      data.splice(i, 1);
      return true;
    } else if (o.children) {
      removeId(o.children, id, o);
    }
  });
}

removeId(data, 1);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This is working, I forgot to mention, would it be difficult that if an item with children is deleted, that the children go to the root?

Comment: @Notflip hum not difficult, but with the recursion fact it won't be so easy. because when the function is called we are loosing the context of parent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm currently trying to implement it in your function, but I don't think it's going to be easy

Comment: @Notflip Actually it can be easy, we just need to pass the parent `object`  to the `function` as well, check my edit for the solution.

Comment: Would this be possible usign array.map as well? Since I'm using Vue, I'm trying to achieve the result with your method, but one that returns, for example: const newData = removeId(data, 1). Since now it's updating the data object that is passed in, instead of creating a new one with the result.

Comment: Well you can do it with both, you just have to perfectly handle the returned object.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I tried using array.map(), but it's breaking the recursiveness, it's returning undefined

Comment: Are you returning the object in each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [],
  }
]

let deletedObj = {}

function deleteAtId(arr, deleteId) {
  const rs = []
  arr.forEach(({id, children}) => {
    if(id !== deleteId) {
      if(!children.length) {
        rs.push({id, children})
      } else {
        const tmp = deleteAtId(children, deleteId)
        rs.push({id, children: tmp})
      }
    } else deletedObj = {id, children}
  })
  return rs
}

const rs = [...deleteAtId(data, 1), {...deletedObj}]

console.log(rs)
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention, would it be difficult that if an item with children is deleted, that the children go to the root?

Comment: @Notflip I updated the answer. Just need a global variable to store the deleted object, then add to the final array.

Comment: What is this $deletedObj, it's sitting outside the function?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? It iterates recursively and splices when it finds an object with your id

```js
function removeObject(data, id){
  data.forEach(point =>{
    if(point.children.length > 0){
      removeObject(point.children, id);
    }
    const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
    if(index > -1){
      data.splice(index ,1);
    }
  });
  return data;
}

const data = [
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [],
  }
]

removeObject(data, 1);

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention, would it be difficult that if an item with children is deleted, that the children go to the root?

Answer (score 0):

Explore the object recursively and delete according to a specified predicate:

```js
const data =[...Array(4)].map(()=> [
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [],
  }
]);

function deleteObj(parent, predicate) {
  if (predicate(parent)) {
    return true;
  }
  if (typeof parent === 'object') {
    if (Array.isArray(parent)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        if (deleteObj(parent[i], predicate)) {
          parent.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      } 
    } else {
      Object.keys(parent).forEach(key => deleteObj(parent[key], predicate) && delete parent[key]);
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log('from array:', data[0]);

const test1 = data[1];
const test2 = data[2];
const test3 = data[3];

console.log('delete node with id === 1');
deleteObj(test1, node => node.id === 1);
console.log(test1);

console.log('delete node with id === 3');
deleteObj(test2, node => node.id === 3);
console.log(test2);

console.log('delete node with non empty children');
deleteObj(test3, node => node.children && node.children.length > 0);
console.log(test3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This recursive function work for your needings:

```js
function rotateChildren(array, key) {
   if (!array || !array.length) {
      return array;
   }

   return array.filter(child => {
      if (child) {
         child.children = rotateChildren(child.children, key);
         return child.id !== key;
      }

      return !!child;
   });
}

const data = [
   {
      id: 2,
      children: [
         {
            id: 1,
            children: []
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      children: [],
   }
];

console.log(rotateChildren(data, 1));
console.log(rotateChildren(data, 2));
console.log(rotateChildren(data, 3));
```

Comment: Would it be possible? If an object with children is deleted, that the children move up to the root?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using Array.reduce with a recursion on the children.

Example:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, children: [{ id: 2, children: [] }] },
  {
    id: 2,
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        children: [
          {
            id: 2,
            children: [
              {
                id: 1,
                children: [],
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

function removeBy(data, predicate) {
  return data.reduce((result, item) => {
    if (!predicate(item.id)) {
      const newItem = { ...item };
      if (item.children.length > 0) {
        newItem.children = removeBy(item.children, predicate);
      }
      result.push(newItem);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}

const predicate = value => value === 1;
const result = removeBy(data, predicate);

console.log(result);
```