# Remove nested object with an Id

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "mode": "onChange",
  "component": "basic",
  "props": {
    "children": [
      {
        "component": "Layout.row",
        "props": {
          "children": [
            {
              "component": "Layout.column",
              "props": {
                "md": 12,
                "lg": 3,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "component": "Layout.label",
                    "props": {
                      "label": "Description"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "component": "Layout.column",
              "props": {
                "md": 12,
                "lg": 8,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "component": "Control.textarea",
                    "control": {
                      "schemaPath": "desc",
                      "message": {
                        "required": "ABC Description is required"
                  
                      }
                    },
                    "props": {
                      "id": "desc",
                      "name": "desc",
                      "label": "XYZ Description"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "component": "Layout.row",
        "props": {
          "id": "companyType",
          "children": [
            {
              "component": "Layout.column",
              "props": {
                "md": 12,
                "lg": 3,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "component": "Layout.label",
                    "props": {
                      "id": "companyType",
                      "label": "Company Type"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "component": "Layout.column",
              "props": {
                "md": 12,
                "lg": 8,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "component": "Control.switch",
                    "control": {
                      "schemaPath": "companyType",
                      "message": {

                      }
                    },
                    "props": {
                      "id": "companyType",
                      "name": "companyType",
                      "label": "Company Type",
                      "moreText": "XYZ",
                      "labelPlacement": "end"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to convert this such that all the props where id = companyType is removed like the component will be removed completely.

I used a nested function but seems it is not working:

```
export const delChildInJSON = (input, childId) => {
  if (input.props) {
    if (input.props.id && input.props.id === childId) {
      console.log("found childId::" + childId);
      return {};
    }
    if (input.props.children && input.props.children.length) {
      const children = input.props.children.map(element => {
        return delChildInJSON(element, childId);
      });
      return { ...input, {...input.props, children: children }};
    }
  }
};
```

spread operator is not working recursively I think so which is causing the issue

I tried this post also:
[Remove a node from a recursive JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75542009/remove-a-node-from-a-recursive-json)

Example:

```js
const json = '{"mode": "onChange","component": "basic","props": {"children": [{"component": "Layout.row","props": {"children": [{"component": "Layout.column","props": {"md": 12,"lg": 3,"children": [{"component": "Layout.label","props": {"label": "Description"}}]}},{"component": "Layout.column","props": {"md": 12,"lg": 8,"children": [{"component": "Control.textarea","control": {"schemaPath": "desc","message": {"required": "ABC Description is required"}},"props": {"id": "desc","name": "desc","label": "XYZ Description"}}]}}]}},{"component": "Layout.row","props": {"id": "companyType","children": [{"component": "Layout.column","props": {"md": 12,"lg": 3,"children": [{"component": "Layout.label","props": {"id": "companyType","label": "Company Type"}}]}},{"component": "Layout.column","props": {"md": 12,"lg": 8,"children": [{"component": "Control.switch","control": {"schemaPath": "companyType","message": {}},"props": {"id": "companyType","name": "companyType","label": "Company Type","moreText": "XYZ","labelPlacement": "end"}}]}}]}}]}}';

const data = JSON.parse(json);

const delChildInJSON = (input, childId) => {
  if (input.props) {
    if (input.props.id && input.props.id === childId) {
      console.log("found childId::" + childId);
      return {};
    }
    if (input.props.children && input.props.children.length) {
      const children = input.props.children.map(element => {
        return delChildInJSON(element, childId);
      });
      return { ...input, {...input.props, children: children }};
    }
  }
};

console.log(delChildInJSON(data, 'companyType'));
```

Comment: You tagged the question with JSON. Please read the tag descriptions before you use a tag and ask a question. The tag description contains: _"Before you ask a question, validate your JSON using a JSON validator such as JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com)."_ Your JSON data isn't valid and can't be parsed.

Comment: Hi corrected and validated json

Comment: I've added a runnable code snippet, but it has an error. Can you fix it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Also, this JSON looks very specifically structure, are you supposed to feed it into some framework? If so, can you handle the logic you want to implement in the framework rather than manually manipulating the JSON?

Comment: This question is not about JSON; once you use `JSON.parse()` it's all just objects and arrays, no longer JSON. JSON is a text format, like XML or CSV.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove object in nested structure by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297306/remove-object-in-nested-structure-by-key)

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to separate the object traversal and filtering from the predicate you use to actually check whether to keep a particular object.

This has an added benefit, as I don't completely understand your requirements, but I can give answers for the two possibilities I see that vary only in the predicate they use.  So, we can write a generic function like this:

```js
const filterDeep = (pred) => (o) => 
  Object (o) === o 
    ? Object .assign (Array .isArray (o) ? [] : {}, ...Object .entries (o) .map (
        ([k, v]) => pred (k, v) ? {[k]: filterDeep (pred) (v)} : {}
      ))
    : o
```

This takes a predicate function, which is recursively supplied keys and values of nested properties in your object, and returns `true` if you want to keep the item.  (This is in keeping with `Array .prototype .filter`, but we could easily write a slightly different version if we wanted to return `true` if we want to *remove* the item.  That is left as an exercise for the reader.)  This works by recursively taking apart the object with `Object .entries`, filtering the resulting key-value pairs and converting those that we keep into `{key: 'recurredValue'}` pairs, and putting them back together into an array or plain object with `Object .assign`.  When the input is not an object, we simply return it.

With this, if we wanted to remove only the `props` node when its `id` matches our target, we can write

```js
const removeId = (id) =>
  filterDeep ((k, v) => k !== 'props' || v.id !== id)
```

and call it like

```js
removeId ('companyType') (input)
```

You can see that in the following snippet:

```js
const filterDeep = (pred) => (o) => 
  Object (o) === o 
    ? Object .assign (Array .isArray (o) ? [] : {}, ...Object .entries (o) .map (
        ([k, v]) => pred (k, v) ? {[k]: filterDeep (pred) (v)} : {}
      ))
    : o
  
const removeId = (id) =>
  filterDeep ((k, v) => k !== 'props' || v.id !== id)

const input = {mode: "onChange", component: "basic", props: {children: [{component: "Layout.row", props: {children: [{component: "Layout.column", props: {md: 12, lg: 3, children: [{component: "Layout.label", props: {label: "Description"}}]}}, {component: "Layout.column", props: {md: 12, lg: 8, children: [{component: "Control.textarea", control: {schemaPath: "desc", message: {required: "ABC Description is required"}}, props: {id: "desc", name: "desc", label: "XYZ Description"}}]}}]}}, {component: "Layout.row", props: {id: "companyType", children: [{component: "Layout.column", props: {md: 12, lg: 3, children: [{component: "Layout.label", props: {id: "companyType", label: "Company Type"}}]}}, {component: "Layout.column", props: {md: 12, lg: 8, children: [{component: "Control.switch", control: {schemaPath: "companyType", message: {}}, props: {id: "companyType", name: "companyType", label: "Company Type", moreText: "XYZ", labelPlacement: "end"}}]}}]}}]}}

console .log (removeId ('companyType') (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But perhaps we got this wrong.  It might be that you want to remove the whole node where there is a `props` property with a matching `id` property.  In that case, we could alter the predicate like this:

```js
const removeId = (id) =>
  filterDeep ((k, v) => v ?.props ?.id !== id)
```

and call it the same way.  This snippet demonstrates that:

```js
const filterDeep = (pred) => (o) => 
  Object (o) === o 
    ? Object .assign (Array .isArray (o) ? [] : {}, ...Object .entries (o) .map (
        ([k, v]) => pred (k, v) ? {[k]: filterDeep (pred) (v)} : {}
      ))
    : o
  
const removeId = (id) =>
  filterDeep ((k, v) => v ?.props ?.id !== id)

const input = {mode: "onChange", component: "basic", props: {children: [{component: "Layout.row", props: {children: [{component: "Layout.column", props: {md: 12, lg: 3, children: [{component: "Layout.label", props: {label: "Description"}}]}}, {component: "Layout.column", props: {md: 12, lg: 8, children: [{component: "Control.textarea", control: {schemaPath: "desc", message: {required: "ABC Description is required"}}, props: {id: "desc", name: "desc", label: "XYZ Description"}}]}}]}}, {component: "Layout.row", props: {id: "companyType", children: [{component: "Layout.column", props: {md: 12, lg: 3, children: [{component: "Layout.label", props: {id: "companyType", label: "Company Type"}}]}}, {component: "Layout.column", props: {md: 12, lg: 8, children: [{component: "Control.switch", control: {schemaPath: "companyType", message: {}}, props: {id: "companyType", name: "companyType", label: "Company Type", moreText: "XYZ", labelPlacement: "end"}}]}}]}}]}}

console .log (removeId ('companyType') (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

In either version, you can partially apply the id of `companyType` like this:

```js
const removeCompanyType = removeId ('companyType')
```

which would let you call it as simply

```js
removeCompanyType (input)
```

Note that the predicate is supplied both the property name and its value.  This is necessary in the first version and irrelevant in the second.  But it's hardly an inconvenience, and it makes the function more powerful.